# HTML layout vertically centered div overlaps header at small heights

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple layout built with a fixed size header and a vertically centered div taking up the rest of the space.

https://jsfiddle.net/jhk7d68s/

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header_container">
        This is some header content
    </div>

    <div class="frame_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="frame">
                This is the frame content
                <br />
                It stretches across three lines
                <br />
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
                <br />
                And could include a link
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
body{padding:0;margin:0;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;background-size:cover;background-color:red;}

.header{height:100px !important;background:black;width:100%;padding-top:0 !important;}
.header_container{padding-top:40px;max-width:1000px;margin:auto;color:white;text-align:center;}

.frame_container{position:absolute;margin-top:50px;top:50%;left:50%;-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);}

.frame{color:black;background:green;padding:20px;text-align:center;}
```

All looks good until you reduce the height of the screen for example, landscape mode on an iPhone.  Then the frame starts to overlap the header.

I assume this is down to the absolute positioning but can't see how to fix it.  I would like scrollbars to appear instead of the frame overlapping.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look like an option?

```css
html, body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  }
body{
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  background-color:red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header{
  height:100px;background:black;width:100%;padding-top:0;
}  
.header_container{
  padding-top:40px;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:auto;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
.container{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.frame_container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.frame{
  color:black;
  background:green;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_container">
    This is some header content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="frame_container">
    <div class="frame">
      This is the frame content
      <br />
      It stretches across three lines
      <br />
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
      <br />
      And could include a link
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That breaks the vertical centering though

Comment: @fightstarr20 You want vertical center relative to the window or the remaining space, below the header ?

Comment: Currently the vertical centering is relative to the remaining space.  I am trying to keep this in place until it reaches the header

Comment: Thats great thanks, flexbox was the way to go with this one

Answer (score 0):

I would use media queries containing a `max-height` condition to change the `absolute` positioning of that container div to `relative` for smaller screens (and maybe adjust some other details too).